# Why is there now a controversy over appointing the Chief Minister of Tamil Nadu?

Tags: india

Prior to her death in December 2016, five term [Tamil Nadu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_Nadu) Chief Minister [Jayalalithaa Jayaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayalalithaa) appointed [O. Panneerselvam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O._Panneerselvam) as her successor.  Now in *February 2016*, that appointment is in dispute: [V. K. Sasikala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._K._Sasikala) demands the [Chief Minister post for herself](http://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/o-panneerselvam-vs-vk-sasikala-10-things-we-know-now-about-the-late-night-drama/story-2tQi2RSib2QD6NtWeloPQK.html).

Why is there now a controversy over appointing the Chief Minister of Tamil Nadu?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I've made some edits to help clear it up, I hope it still reflects what you wanted to ask. I wasn't sure what you meant by disturbed though, and I think that is confusing some people. Can you help us clear that up? Also, would you have a link to a news article (preferable in English) about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might know, Sasikala is a companion of Jayalalitha and Panneerselvam is a staunch loyalist. After the death of Jayalalitha, Panneerselvam assumed office as Chief Minister as he did earlier, to serve as pro-temp Chief Minister of State.

However, the situation now is that Panneerselvam has rebelled saying that "he was forced to step down as Chief Minister," and can continue to be Chief Minister of State. The situation is that the Members of the Legislative Assembly of the parties are now being taken to a unknown place by Sasikala to stop Panneerselvam gaining trust of those MLA's to support him as their leader.

> On Tuesday, in a dramatic twist, outgoing Tamil Nadu Chief Minister O
>   Panneerselvam openly rebelled against AIADMK Chief VK Sasikala and said
>   that he was forced to step down from the CM post. He said, "I will
>   take back my resignation if party workers and people ask me to."

Now Sasikala is presenting herself as the leader of the Members of the Legislative Assembly, by gaining support and awaiting the invitation from the Governor to form a government.

There is more to come.

**Refrences:**

- http://www.firstpost.com/politics/outgoing-tn-cm-o-panneerselvam-openly-rebels-against-sasikala-says-will-take-back-resignation-if-asked-to-3271378.html
- http://www.firstpost.com/india/jayalalithaa-sasikala-natarajan-friendship-soul-sisters-whose-relationship-soured-3141452.html
- http://www.deccanchronicle.com/nation/current-affairs/080217/after-sasikala-slams-ops-aiadmk-legislators-moved-to-undisclosed-location.html